# Deserialising REST XML response into object - failing on valid XML

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, xml-deserialization, windows-10-iot-core

I try to deserialise an xml document object obtained from REST web server. This is exact response I got from server (valid XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ads:body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:ads="http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema">
    <ads:header>
        <ads:createdBy>Polaris</ads:createdBy>
        <ads:dateTimeCreated>2016-01-20T10:22:23Z</ads:dateTimeCreated>
    </ads:header>
    <ads:animals count="2">
        <ads:animal>
            <ads:internalIdentifier>1</ads:internalIdentifier>
            <ads:eid>982 000360237659</ads:eid>
            <ads:dob>2012-05-01</ads:dob>
            <ads:breed>Angus</ads:breed>
            <ads:customLifeTimeData>
                <ads:name>VID</ads:name>
                <ads:value>TTDEMO1</ads:value>
            </ads:customLifeTimeData>
        </ads:animal>
        <ads:animal>
            <ads:internalIdentifier>2</ads:internalIdentifier>
            <ads:eid>982 000359951630</ads:eid>
            <ads:dob>2012-05-02</ads:dob>
            <ads:breed>Angus</ads:breed>
            <ads:customLifeTimeData>
                <ads:name>VID</ads:name>
                <ads:value>TTDEMO2</ads:value>
            </ads:customLifeTimeData>
        </ads:animal>
    </ads:animals>
</ads:body>
```

The object class I use to deserialise would be this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ***.IOT.Schemas
{
    public class ADI_animal
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "header", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
        public class Header
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "createdBy", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "dateTimeCreated", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public string DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "customLifeTimeData", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
        public class CustomLifeTimeData
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "name", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "value", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "animal", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
        public class Animal
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "internalIdentifier", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public string InternalIdentifier { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "eid", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public string Eid { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "dob", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public string Dob { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "breed", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public string Breed { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "customLifeTimeData", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public CustomLifeTimeData CustomLifeTimeData { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "animals", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
        public class Animals
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "animal", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public List<Animal> Animal { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "count")]
            public string Count { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "body", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]

        public class Body
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "header", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public Header Header { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "animals", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public Animals Animals { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
            public string Xsi { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ads", Namespace = "http://www.ads.org/AnimalDataSchema")]
            public string Ads { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

The debug output is:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.GeneratedCode
The thread 0xdfc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb34 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll
exception caught: There is an error in XML document (1, 40).
```

The code I run:

```
   static public void ProcessResponse(XmlDocument queryResponse)
   {
            String queryRootString;
            ADI_animal adsObject = new ADI_animal();
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
            {
                XmlDocument queryRoot = queryResponse;
                queryRoot.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
                xmlTextWriter.Flush();
                queryRootString = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ADI_animal));

                adsObject = (ADI_animal)result.Deserialize(new StringReader(queryRootString));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("exception caught: " + ex.Message);
            }
}
```

Pretty much tells me that the XML document has a problem with the namespace. But I just can't find the mistake. Maybe someone can give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: "looks like this" (and showing valid XML) is not going to be helpful... You need to get actual string that you are trying to load (which may immediately give you an answer).

Comment: OK. "Looks like this" means " THIS is the XML response I got " . Sorry, just a matter of how I formulated the question. Did a Debug.WriteLine(queryResponse); , then copied and pasted it (and formatted it with line breaks and indentations, so that you can better read it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize XML that looks like `ADI_animal.Body` by serializer that is configured to expect `ADI_animal` as top level object.

Not exactly sure what you are looking for but desirializing that XML as `ADI_animal.Body` instance should work fine:

```
XmlSerializer result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ADI_animal.Body));
var body = (ADI_animal.Body)result.Deserialize(new StringReader(queryRootString));
```

---

Debugging note: to simplify investigations of deserialization try to  serialize object first to see what shape of XML is expected:

```
XmlSerializer result2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ADI_animal));
var w = new StringWriter();
result2.Serialize(w, new ADI_animal());
Console.WriteLine(w.ToString());
```

Comment: Yes! That's it. You're completely right! Simple and I still didn't see it. Thanks!